# how to make text to speech converter in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, text-to-speech

I have seen many BlackBerry phones with text to speech that reads the user's mail.
I want to make an application which reads text.

Answer (score 1):

See [Text to Speech in j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652603/text-to-speech-in-j2me)

I'd rather say it's possible to create enterprise solution with web service on server side which will consume text and return some audio data in result. It would be fast enough inside of local wifi network of company.

[list of open source TTS projects](http://www.babelfish.org/tts-free.htm)